# Trouble of essential c++ Q1.8

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ by reading c++ essential. But the program is interrupted at ***`expected a ","`***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const char* msg_to_usr(int num_tries)
    {
        const int rsp_cnt = 5;
        static const char* usr_msgs( rsp_cnt ) = {
            "Go on,male a guess.",
            "Oops! Nice quess but not quite it.",
            "Hmm.Sorry Wrong again",
            "Ah, this is harder than it looks,no?",
            "It must be getting pretty frustrating by now!"
        };
        if (num_tries < 0)
            num_tries = 0;
        else
        if (num_tries >= rsp_cnt)
            num_tries = rsp_cnt - 1;
        return usr_msgs(num_tries);
        
    }
    
}
```

Have somebody to help me out of this confusion?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points:

1. Nowhere in that book does it try to define that function *inside* `main()`, which is causing a problem for you. In fact, it just shows you the function itself devoid of anything that would let you run it, leaving you to add that (incorrectly as it turns out). Books that include *complete* programs (see my code below for an example) are generally better since they help beginners avoid that particular class of mistake (having to add stuff to see it in action).
2. You're using `()` in a couple of places where it's `[]` in the book (with `usr_msgs`), turning *array* accesses into invalid function definitions and calls. The code below would be a good starting point for further exploration (with both those issues fixed, and fixing the content of some of the messages as a side issue):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char *msg_to_usr(int num_tries) {
    const int rsp_cnt = 5;
    static const char *usr_msgs[rsp_cnt] = {
        "Go on, make a guess.",
        "Oops! Nice guess but not quite it.",
        "Hmm. Sorry Wrong again.",
        "Ah, this is harder than it looks, no?",
        "It must be getting pretty frustrating by now!"
    };
    if (num_tries < 0)
        num_tries = 0;
    else if (num_tries >= rsp_cnt)
        num_tries = rsp_cnt - 1;
    return usr_msgs[num_tries];
}

int main() {
    // Test harness.
    for (int tries = 0; tries < 10; ++tries)
        cout << msg_to_usr(tries) << '\n';
}
```

---

Just for completeness, here's an image of the entire snippet from the book, with indications as to where your code deviated:
[image]